# Aligning two container's items with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to align inner items, without using fixed heights(or alike) and without breaking the semantics(it should be structured/layout (html) properly).

It's better to see an example to understand what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/5oth3xag/

HTML:

```
<div class="list">

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p></p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,div,h2 {margin:0; padding:0;}
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.heading {

}
.para {

}
.something_else {
  color: red;
}
.link {

}
```

I want the `This needed to be aligned` to be aligned with the item next to it. Obviously, if they are the same - it will be. But once something changed, it brakes. For example:

```
<div class="list">

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore</p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

So, I want the `This needed to be aligned` be aligned to the one that is stretched. I hope you understand what am I meaning by all this.

I don't mind to use flexbox, etc. as long as it will support modern browsers.

Is this even possible or am I wanting too much of CSS?

Comment: In my jsfiddle example I used `min-height` to demonstrate desirable result. I don't mind about spacing, but I do mind about fixing heights(with min-height etc), because this(text) all will be dynamically changed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using flexbox, flex-direction and flex-grow.

Add the `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to your `.item{}`.

Create a new class for your second `.para{}` like `.para2{}`.

Add `flex-grow: 1;` to `.para2{}` and it work.

Here is your code with the modification.

```css
html,body,div,h2 {margin:0; padding:0;}
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  max-width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
.heading {
  
}
.para {
  min-height: 170px;
}
.para2{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.something_else {
  color: red;
}
.link {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore</p>
    <div class="something_else">
      This needed to be aligned
    </div>
    <p class="para2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam deserunt facilis animi voluptatibus tempore, et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!et earum commodi doloribus fuga delectus repellat ut eligendi soluta praesentium eum sapiente dolore iste asperiores!</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">This needed to be aligned</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: But the `para` won't be aligned in this case... only the `para2`. if you remove the `min-height: 170px` and add `flex-grow: 1;` it won't affect the middle `This needed to be aligned`

Comment: I understand. With this structure and without Javascript I don't know any viable solution in pure CSS :/

Comment: the block's you would align are differents, some are link's some are div's. So with this structure i don't know how to align but you can define this elements absolute and position them from the bottom. But you have to modify a little this structure